# Datatables TableTools with Excel,pdf exporting functions not working with firefox but working only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, datatables, cross-browser, tabletools

Datatables TableTools with Excel,pdf exporting functions not working with firefox
I have tried to export to the Excel and PDF using Datatables TableTools and have checked all other posts, nothing seems to get it working in firefox; it works fine in chrome and IE. Please suggest me

function BindDataTable(targetGrid) {

```
    var sortableGrid = $(targetGrid).attr('id');
    //$('#' + sortableGrid).DataTable();
    var table = $('#' + sortableGrid).DataTable({
        "bFilter": false, //hide Search bar
    });

    var tableTools = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools(table, {
        'aButtons': [
            {
                'sExtends': 'xls',
                'sButtonText': 'Save to Excel',
                'sFileName': 'TableList.xls'
            },               
            {
                'sExtends': 'pdf',
                'sFileName': 'TableList.pdf'                  
            },               
            {
                'sExtends': 'csv',
                'sFileName': 'TableList.csv'               
            }   

        ],
        'sSwfPath':'http://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.2/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf'
    });
    var idwrapper = $('#' + sortableGrid).attr('id') + "_wrapper";       
    $(tableTools.fnContainer()).insertBefore('#'+idwrapper);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it could be `Flash` issue. Please try to reinstalled `Flash`.